# Loop through array with Mandrill in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mandrill

I've set up a mailer using the Mandrill API in my Ruby on Rails app, for sending out a daily activity report for a user.

```
class ReportMailer < BaseMandrillMailer
  def send_report(user_id)
    user = User(user_id)
    posts = Posts.where("userID == ?", user.id)
    subject = "Subject line"
    merge_vars = {
     "name" => user.name

     posts.each do |p|
       "title" => p.title # Line 10
     end
    } # Line 12

    body = mandrill_template("template-name", merge_vars)

    send_mail(user.email, subject, body)
 end
end # Line 18
```

As you can see I tried using a standard for-loop inside the merge_vars to iterate through every post that user has made, so that they appear as a list in my MailChimp/Mandrill template.

However, this code gives me the following SyntaxError:

```
.../report_mailer.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end "title" => p.title ^~ 

.../report_mailer.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end } ^ 

.../report_mailer.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Here is their documentation I've been trying to follow:
http://blog.mandrill.com/handlebars-for-templates-and-dynamic-content.html#examples

Comment: what's weird syntax error?

Comment: Hi @KickButtowski just updated the post with the error log.

Comment: could you mark lines 10, 12, and 18?

Comment: r u sure about? posts.each do |p|
       "title" => p.title
     end. doesn't look right

Comment: Sure, please check updated post.